# Do I need a level converter for Raspberry Pi and STM32 to communicate via GPIO(UART) port?

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, stm32, raspberry-pi4, stm32f4discovery

I want to connect an STM32F407 Discovery board with a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

And I want to use UART as communication so I plan to use PD5&6 on STM32 and Pin8&10 on RPi. But after looking up online it says that the voltage of a STM32 port is 5V and RPi is 3.3V, so it seems that I need a level converter between them?

And there are also some articles says that not all the STM32 port are 5V, some are 3.3V. But I cannot find any of that information in the datasheet. Can anyone tell me where can I find these information?

Thank you very much ~ ~

Comment: This is a hardware question and should have been asked on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it's documented. You might need to look again, perhaps in more documents, search especially for your specific parts.

Comment: @Codo Oh sorry... I didn't know that. Should I delete this post and repost there? I will remeber it next time!

Comment: @thebusybee [This](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084-discovery-kit-with-stm32f407vg-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) is only the datasheet I found online. I look through it but the onlything I found is that it can tolerant 5V. It doesn't say what is the output voltage. Maybe I miss something? Or maybe this is not the document I should look for?

Comment: Yes. Please delete this and post over there. It has no place here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STM32 uses 3.3V as well. But it's 5V tolerant.

Just go ahead and connect them. There is no voltage difference.

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much~ But may I ask where you find the specs? I look into this [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084-discovery-kit-with-stm32f407vg-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and did not find any of that information. And this is the only datasheet I can find online. Did I miss something? Or there is another datasheet that I haven't found? Thanks again~

Comment: I didn't actually look into the datasheet. But I've dealt with STM32s sufficiently (incl. custom designs) to know that the output voltage is the same as VCC and VCC is usually 3.3V (and 4.0V absolute max). And the 5V tolerance discussion wouldn't be needed if they'd run with 5V in the first place. If you really want to know, check the [STM32F407xx datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf) (not the one from the development board) and possibly the STM32F4DISCOVERY schematic. A multimeter also comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the reference manual for that discovery board.  It is here: [STM32F407 Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

There should be no issue connecting UARTs between those boards.  Just remember to connect the TX from one to the RX of the other and vice versa.  You can also use the CTS/RTS for flow control, but that isn't necessary as long as you are using baud rates of 115200 or slower.

Something else that I would recommended is to power the Raspberry Pi from the Discovery board.  There should be pins for suitable power on the discovery.  This is important because it gets both boards using the same power and ground so that the UART logic levels are consistent between the two.  This may not be necessary, but I have had issues trying to connect two Nucleo boards SPI busses together if I didn't power one board from the other.